# Flutter over corporate Proxy

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, proxy

Failed to run Flutter Doctor in **windows over corporate proxy**.
I set proxy setting using below commands,

- **set http_proxy=USER:PWD@PROXY_URL:PORT**
- **set https_proxy=USER:PWD@PROXY_URL:PORT**

But still it gives error.

**Error Code:**
Checking Dart SDK version...
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b5d1d2d8c8c37...
Downloading the Dart SDK using the BITS service failed, retrying with WebRequest...
Invoke-WebRequest :
Access Denied (authentication_failed)
Your credentials could not be authenticated: "Credentials are missing.". You will not be permitted access until your
credentials can be verified.
This is typically caused by an incorrect username and/or password, but could also be caused by network problems.
At D:\RAHUL_1647164\flutter_dev\flutter\bin\internal\update_dart_sdk.ps1:68 char:5
+     Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $dartSdkUrl -OutFile $dartSdkZip
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
Error: Unable to update Dart SDK. Retrying...